# How to access child class's datamember when both base and child class have same object name but different types. in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, parent-child

```
struct BaseType
{
    int x1;
    float x2;
};

struct ChildType
{
    int y1;
    float y2;
};

Class Base       
{             
    BaseType  obj;           

    void funcBase(BaseType **ptr)
    {

        *ptr = &obj;                   // When this assignment happens ofcourse obj is of the BaseType as the  LHS ptr is pointing to a BaseType                                            

  Now I want to write a C++ equivalent code of the following 2 algorithmic statements,                                       

        BaseType's obj.x1 = ChildTypes's obj.y1;                       
        BaseType's obj.x2 = ChildTypes's.obj.y1;                  


    }               
};

class Child :: public Base
{
    ChildType obj;  

};
```

I wnat to access child's obj.y1 from base and assign it to base's obj.x1.

> But 1 thing to remember that object name in base and child is same
>   "obj".

Can anyone kindly help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: Sean's answer seems to be a good match for your question (assuming that his interpretation of your question is the right one), but it is not clear what you are asking. Why are you trying to access a data member of a Child object from a member function of a Base object? A description of your overall goal (or code example demonstrating it) would be helpful.

Comment: What is your end goal?  As Alex Z stated, it's possible, but I don't particularly recommend it.  The base class should not have to know about it's child class.  That kind of steps of the toes of inheritance.  What happens if obj actually is a BaseType and you try to treat it like a ChildType?  Bad, bad things.

Comment: Indeed a different design is probably the way to go here..

Comment: Sorry that my earlier explanation of question seemed to be vague and confusing for many folks. So I have added necessary additions to my code. Please can u refer to it.

Comment: Encapsulate! Objects combine data and behaviour, hiding the data. If you find yourself doing fiddly things with other classes` data, even using `get`s and `set`s then you've failed. It's best to think about what behaviour the `Base` has and what new behaviour you want the `Dervived` class to introduce. Then design the `Base` class to delegate to `Derived` for the behaviour variation. You do this using `virtual` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague, but from what I can gather, you want something like this:

```
ChildType* child = dynamic_cast<ChildType*>( &obj );
```

Now `child` is pointing to `obj`, as if it were of type `ChildType`, assuming the cast is successful.

Read more about typecasting [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

**EDIT:** I should just mention that typecasting like this should be avoided if a better design can substitute it. Perhaps you should reconsider your overall design for a moment here.

**EDIT2:** Given your recent edit, here's a more specific block of example code:

```
ChildType* child = dynamic_cast<ChildType*>( &obj );
obj.x1 = child->y1;
obj.x2 = child->y2;
```

Comment: I've edited my response with another example tailored to your recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you have an object of type Child that does not implement funcBase() and that you want to call funcBase() on this object and have funcBase() access Child::obj and not Base::obj.  If that's the case then I *believe* you can define Child as

```
class Child : virtual public Base
{
    ChildType obj;
    ...
}
```

[Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) is usually used to resolve the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) but I *think* you can use it to solve this problem as well.

If my assumption is incorrect then feel free to ignore me.